# How to turn off logging for SqlAlchemy db pool only, when debugging is enabled in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, logging, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

### Context / environment

I have a Python Django project connecting to a PostgreSQL database with a SqlAlchemy `django-postgrespool2` db pool.

### What I'm trying to achieve

In `settings.py` I have set `DEBUG = True` which will make the program log. However, I want to disable the logging coming from the SqlAlchemy db pool only, while having `DEBUG` set to `True`. In other words, when debugging, I want to see all logs except for the ones coming from the SqlAlchemy db pool.

### What I've tested

The code below shows too different attempts I've made to disable the db pool logging:

```
def turnOffLog(self):
        # --- Attempt 1, db pool logs still show ---
        logging.basicConfig()
        logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        # --- Attempt 2, db pool logs still show ---
        sqla_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine')
        for hdlr in sqla_logger.handlers:
            sqla_logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
```

I also pass `echo=False` to the QueuePool instance when I create it, which still doesn't remove the logs:

```
dbPool = pool.QueuePool(dbConnection, max_overflow=dbConfig.poolMaxOverflow, pool_size=dbConfig.poolSize, recycle=dbConfig.poolRecycleTime, pre_ping=dbConfig.prePing, dialect=postgresql.dialect(), echo=False)
```

My `settings.py` file (DEBUG is set to True from an env-config file):

```
"""
myapp
"""

import os
import logging
import socket
import sys
from decouple import Config, RepositoryEnv

import time

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# DECOUPLE
# env_config = Config(RepositoryEnv(BASE_DIR.replace('myapp-gui','')+'.env'))
env_config = Config(RepositoryEnv("c:\\Users\\myteam\\Documents\\django\\ATT49882.env"))

print('Using database:          \x1b[97m[\033[92m '+env_config.get('DB_NAME')+' \x1b[97m]\033[0m');
print('Using database host:     \x1b[97m[\033[92m '+env_config.get('DB_HOST')+' \x1b[97m]\033[0m');
print('Using database port:     \x1b[97m[\033[92m '+env_config.get('DB_PORT')+' \x1b[97m]\033[0m');

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env_config.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# OLD DEBUG = bool(env_config.get('DEBUG'))
try:
    DEBUG = bool(int(env_config.get('DEBUG')))
except Exception as err:
    DEBUG = True 

# LOGLEVEL
if DEBUG:
    LOGLEVEL = "DEBUG"
else:
    LOGLEVEL = "INFO"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# myapp version
if DEBUG:
    myapp_VERSION = time.time()
else:
    myapp_VERSION = 2.0

# myapp constants
myapp_CONSTANTS = {
    'myapp_VERSION': myapp_VERSION
}

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.mrank-middleware.MrankMiddleware',
    'core.context_processor.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = []

REQUEST_WHITELIST_IP = ['127.0.0.1']

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'core.views.csrf_failure'

# Setting for searching for HTML files in all templates folders, even in subfolders
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'core.context_processor.serverconfig',
                'core.context_processor.phraseconfig',
                'core.context_processor.myapp_constants'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

# FOR DEVELOPMENT :-)
try:

    hostname = socket.gethostname()
except:
    hostname = ''


# bool(int(env_config.get('DEBUG')))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': env_config.get('DB_NAME'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=myappdjango'
        },
        'USER': env_config.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env_config.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env_config.get('DB_HOST'),   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': env_config.get('DB_PORT')
    },
    'pool': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_postgrespool2', 
        'NAME': env_config.get('DB_NAME'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=myappdjango'
        },
        'USER': env_config.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env_config.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env_config.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env_config.get('DB_PORT'),
        'POOL_SIZE': int(env_config.get('DB_POOL_SIZE', 100)),
        'POOL_MAX_OVERFLOW': int(env_config.get('DB_POOL_MAX_OVERFLOW', 100)),
        'POOL_RECYCLE_TIME': int(env_config.get('DB_POOL_RECYCLE_TIME', 3600)),
        "PRE_PING": bool(int(env_config.get('DB_POOL_PRE_PING', 0)))
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    ...
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Upload directory
MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')

# Custom settings
TIME = 60*60*60*60
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = TIME
SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT = TIME
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'stream': sys.stdout
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': LOGLEVEL,
    },
}
```

### Db pool log example

Just an example of how the logs look I want to remove:

```
2021-03-24 09:38:00:DEBUG:z.pool: new connection
2021-03-24 09:38:00:DEBUG:z.pool: retrieved from pool
2021-03-24 09:38:00:DEBUG:z.pool: returned to pool
```

Thanks!

### Update #0

I also tried this, but still it doesn't remove the db pool logs:

```
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').disable = True
```

Comment: Have you also tried `sqlalchemy.pool` as the logger name?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by setting **engine.echo = False** where engine = create_engine()

It seems that sqlalchemy creates its own log output:

> It’s important to note that these two flags work independently of any existing logging configuration, and will make use of logging.basicConfig() unconditionally. This has the effect of being configured in addition to any existing logger configurations. Therefore, when configuring logging explicitly, ensure all echo flags are set to False at all times, to avoid getting duplicate log lines.

You should set your engine.echo and/or engine.echo_pool to False (engine = create_engine()).

In my case (almost identical to this one) **engine.echo = False** solved the problem and engine.echo_pool was not found.

Here is more description: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#more-on-the-echo-flag